# WEBPACK - How to get individual build file from a javascript import

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I have this javascript

```
import cards './cards-grid.scss' 
import key_point from './key-point.scss'
import contact_form from './contact-form.scss'
```

in my webpack there is this entry and this output

```
entry: path.join(__dirname, '../scss/blocks/blocks.js'),

 output: {
   filename: 'block.bundle.js',
   path: path.join(__dirname, '../../assets/blocks')
},
```

Obviously I have all the CSS in one file, but I would like to get a css file for each import, so:

```
assets/blocks/cards-grid.min.css
assets/blocks/key-point.min.css
assets/blocks/contact-form.min.css
```

Do you think it's possible? has anyone had the same need? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you importing your styles in js?? Use `css-loader` and `sass-loader`:

```
module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
            ]
        }]
    }
```

OR you need to add `[name]` into output file name. It will then not bundle all into one file, but this will not work for styles (.scss files):

```
output: {
   filename: '[name].js',
   path: path.join(__dirname, '../../assets/blocks')
},
```

Comment: Thanks,
This is my code about css
```
module: {
 rules: [{
  test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
   fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
     { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
     {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
       plugins: () =>
       autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 3 versions', '> 1%']
       })
      }
     },
      { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
     ],
     fallback: 'style-loader'
  })
 }]
},
```
So do you think it is not possible to have individual files?